# How to display a character value in the get method as a String value in the set method

Tags: java

I have the animal class below. Now, there is the Test file for the `Animal` class.

I am trying to take the character value `m` and display it as a `male`. Not sure where to put the logic at. Do I put it in the setGender method or somewhere else. please advise with the answer.

```
package chapter4;

public class Animal {
    private int lifeExpectancy;
    private int weight;
    String name;
    Character gender;
    public String type;
    /*
    public void printValues() {
        String animal = new String();
        System.out.println(lifeExpectancy + "" + weight + "" + name + "" + gender + "" + type);
    }
    */


    public Animal(int lifeExpectancy, int weight, String name, Character gender, String type) {
        //super();
        this.lifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getLifeExpectancy() {
        return lifeExpectancy;
    }

    public void setLifeExpectancy(int lifeExpectancy) {
        this.lifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }



    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public  Character getGender() {
        /*
        if (gender == 'm' || gender == 'M')
            //gender.equals(obj)"Male";
          this.setGender(gender);
          return "Male";
        */
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Character gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

/*

    public String printValues() {
        return "Animal [lifeExpectancy=" + lifeExpectancy + ", weight=" + weight + ", name=" + name + ", gender="
                + gender + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }
*/

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal [lifeExpectancy=" + lifeExpectancy + ", weight=" + weight + ", name=" + name + ", gender="
                + gender + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }

}
```

Testing Animal Class

```
public class AnimalTst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal (65, 14000 ,"Jumbo", 'm', "elephant");

        System.out.println("A " + animal.getGender() + " " + animal.getType() + " named " + animal.getName() 
        + " should live to be " + animal.getLifeExpectancy() + " and weigh " + animal.getWeight() + " pounds");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is that how to *display* the value should be **decided at the point where it is displayed**; it shouldn't necessarily be a feature of the `Animal` class. It's a question of separation of responsablities.  An `Animal`'s only job with regard to gender should be to know what gender it is.  It *shouldn't* be, and in fact *can't* be,  expected to cope with the details of presenting this information to the outside world.

Just imagine all the different ways you might need to show an `Animal`'s gender to a human:

The simplest case is when you need to insert the word "male" or "female" into a sentence, such as "This gender of this animal is ???".

In another, you might need the capitalized form "Male" or "Female" at the start of a sentence: "??? animals such as this one...".

In another, you might need the possessive form "male's" or "female's": "The ??? coloration blends in with its surroundings..."

In another, you might need the French equivalents "mâle" and "femelle": "Sexe de cet animal est ???".

In another, you might show the gender on a GUI by selecting the appropriate one of a pair of radio-buttons labeled "Male" and "Female".

Answer (score 0):

a `Character` is exactly that, one character, you can't return "male" because that is several characters. What you could do is change `gender` from a `Character` type to a `String` type, you could then take in 'm' or 'M' as a `Character` and use that to create logic that will set `gender` to "Male" which would be a `String`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are invoking the getter on gender, thats where you will need your logic to display the full form of the gender.

You can add an enum for GENDER in your Animal class

```
private enum GENDER {Male, Female};
```

And your getter can have the logic to return the full form for display purpose.

```
public  String getGender() {
        return (this.gender == 'm' ? GENDER.Male.name() : GENDER.Female.name());
    }
```

Also your toString method in Animal class can use the getter methods to avoid replicating that logic there.

Comment: ok the method character get gender should enum get gender. I tried that and it error saying type mismatch between enum and character any comments.

Comment: my bad. Updated the answer. You will need to change the return type to String and return the String form of the enum

Comment: I prefer Kevin's answer, that you don't want the logic to return the display string in the `Animal` class.  However, if you do, I think you _still_ need a method to return the actual value (a `Character` in the original example, but I like the idea of making it an `enum`).  Having `getGender` return a `String`, and not having any method that returns a  simpler value, is a poor idea.

Comment: Also, the convention for enums is to make the class name camel-case like any class (thus, `Gender`), and to make the enum values upper-case (thus, `MALE` and `FEMALE`).  In this case, you wouldn't be able to use `name()` to get the desired string--which is fine, I think, since enum constant identifiers shouldn't have to match strings you want to display (what if you decide to add a case with a space or hyphen in it?).

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a string ( or array of characters ), do this in your `getGender()` method :

```
public  Character getGender() 
{
   return this.gender;
}
```

and in your `main()`:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{

    System.out.println("A " + ( animal.getGender().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("m") ? "Male" : animal.getGender().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("f") ? "Female" : "Unknown") + " " + animal.getType() + " named " + animal.getName() 
    + " should live to be " + animal.getLifeExpectancy() + " and weigh " + animal.getWeight() + " pounds");


}
```

Use conditional to compare character's string value to "m"/"f" and print "Male" or "Female" or may be "Unknown" too.

Comment: You should consider upvoting answers that you get.